# Users cannot view tables in non-default schema in SSMS

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, security, ssms, permissions

I'm having an issue setting the `VIEW DEFINITION` permission appropriately at the schema level for one of my users. I've created the schema `TestSchema` and added some tables. The user currently has permissions set to access & modify the table (`SELECT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE`, etc) through the `dbo_datareader` and `dbo_datawriter` roles. However, they cannot see any of the tables in the SSMS object explorer.

I've tried granting permissions to view definitions:

```
grant view definition on SCHEMA :: [TestSchema] to [User]
```

That didn't work. I tried setting the table-level permission:

```
grant view definition on [TestSchema].[NewTable] to [User]
```

That also didn't work. Then I tried just a blanket grant:

```
grant view definition to [User]
```

And that *did* work; they can now see `TestSchema`, as well as other schemas that they shouldn't have access to.

My goal here is to allow the user to view all tables within a given schema. How do I accomplish that? If I *should* be able to do this by default, what permissions should I be looking at to find why I can't?

Comment: On my 2008R2 instance when I grant db_datareader or db_datawriter they can see all schemas.  I do realize that's not what you're looking for but it means there's a significant difference between your setup and mine so I can't really test it.  Is the version all that's different or has some other security been modified?

Comment: @cfradenburg - It's difficult to tell; this is a server managed by IT, so I'm not sure what they did, and I'm a SQL Server novice, so I don't know what to look for. I guess part of my question is, what other permissions/roles/??? should I look for to determine if this can be simply fixed by permissions?

Comment: Can the user query the tables? If they can query then it could just be an issue within SSMS.

Comment: @user9164 Yes, the users **can** query the tables; it's just an issue of viewing them within SSMS.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Short answer: Don't use `db_datareader` or `db_datawriter` or their deny equivalents. They are for backwards compatibility only. Using them will cause issues like the one you are facing.

If you want to give principal Alice the SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE permissions to all table-valued objects in schema Sales then use the following.

```
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON SCHEMA::Sales TO Alice ;
```

If you want to give principal Alice the SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE permissions to all table-valued objects in all schemas then use the following.

```
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE TO Alice ;
```

Metadata visibility will then work correctly.

Comment: Do you have a source for the 'backwards compatibility' bit? I understand the schemas are deprecated, but I can't find anything about the roles.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the principals other permissions there might be a deny in there somewhere that is is causing the problem. Remember a deny will always apply over the top of a grant. And as its not your servr there might somthing in the account that the IT dept have set up.

Use somthing like this for server level:

```
    use master
    go
    SELECT a.*,b.name as 'Login ID' FROM sys.server_permissions as A inner join 
    sys.server_principals as B on a.grantee_principal_id = b.principal_id
    where b.name = 'login ID of the account'
    GO
```

And somthing like this at database level

```
SELECT a.*,b.name as 'Login ID' FROM sys.database_permissions as A 
inner join sys.server_principals as B on a.grantee_principal_id = b.principal_id
where b.name = 'test'
GO
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I'll try this out when I get back to work on Monday.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me when I upgraded our SQL Server from 2008R2 to 2014. 
db_datareader or db_datawriter or their deny equivalents perfectly work fine in 2008R2 but they doesn't work in 2014.

**Example to grant permission in SQL Server 2014**

If you want to give user Alice the SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE permissions to all table-valued objects in schema Sales then use the following.

GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON SCHEMA::Sales TO Alice ;
If you want to give principal Alice the SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE permissions to all table-valued objects in all schemas then use the following.

GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE TO Alice ;
Metadata visibility will then work correctly.

> Reference [Greenstone Walker].

Comment: Sundeep, please try to explain an answer instead of just providing a link. If you need any help, check out the [site tour](http://dba.stackexchange.com/tour)